# How to change a pdf background color?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, pymupdf

I want to change the background of the PDF file.
I have to make this change monthly with some PDF files.
I hope you can assist with this automation.
I am open to solutions using other libraries

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4 #letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

input_pdf_path = "input_pdf_path.pdf"
output_pdf_path = "output.pdf"

background_color = (185, 231, 186)

c = canvas.Canvas(input_pdf_path, pagesize=A4)
c.setFillColorRGB(*[x / 255 for x in background_color])
c.rect(0, 0, A4[0], A4[1], fill=True)
c.setTitle("Background")
c.showPage()
c.save()

input_pdf = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)
output_pdf = fitz.open(output_pdf_path)

# I'm stuck here

output_pdf.save(output_pdf_path)
output_pdf.close()

print("Background color changed and saved to", output_pdf_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is super simple, short and fast in PyMuPDF:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

input_pdf_path = "input_pdf_path.pdf"
output_pdf_path = "output.pdf"
background_color = (185/255, 231/255, 186/255)

doc = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)
for page in doc:
    page.draw_rect(page.rect, color=None, fill=background_color, overlay=False)

doc.ez_save(output_pdf_path)
doc.close()
print("Background color changed and saved to", output_pdf_path)
```

Also, you do not need any other library.

Comment: hank you for the feedback. I appreciate your comments. However, the output file is the same. Don't changed the background

Comment: This means that you already have some background color. This is a complication which must be resolved by removing what is there. Can you share an example? Maybe on this Discord channel: https://discord.com/channels/770681584617652264/983871937711341618

Comment: Clicking the link, it indicates that I don't have access to the channel or that the server doesn't exist. 
Can you add me? My username is leonlaboi.

Comment: Try this link - it is an invitation: https://discord.gg/BZ9SF2FR

Comment: jorj-mckie is a heroe!
He helped me to understand and adjust the code to work!

Answer (score 1):

You may check the following example which uses Spire.Pdf for Python (**pip install Spire.Pdf**):

```
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

# Create a PdfDocument object
doc = PdfDocument()

# Load a PDF file
doc.LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\input.pdf")

# Loop through each page in the document
for i in range(doc.Pages.Count):        
    page = doc.Pages[i]    
    # Set a background color for the page
    page.BackgroundColor = Color.get_LightYellow()

# Save the document to a different file
doc.SaveToFile("output/SetBackgroundColor.pdf")
doc.Close()
```

More details can be found in this article: [Python: Set a Background Color or Image for PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.PDF-for-Python/Program-Guide/Page-Setting/Python-Set-a-Background-Color-or-Image-for-PDF.html)

Disclaimer: I work for the company that developed this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_colored_background` function, and then you have to define your own rgb colors, you can find those from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp), and then you can mention your input and output pdfs

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import io

def add_colored_background(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, background_color=(255, 165, 0)):
    # RGB color values for orange
    r, g, b = background_color
    r /= 255.0
    g /= 255.0
    b /= 255.0

    input_pdf = PdfReader(open(input_pdf_path, 'rb'))
    output_pdf = PdfWriter()

    for page_num in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
        page = input_pdf.pages[page_num]
        packet = io.BytesIO()
        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.setFillColorRGB(r, g, b)
        can.rect(0, 0, letter[0], letter[1], fill=True, stroke=False)
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfReader(packet)
        page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
        output_pdf.add_page(page)

    with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_pdf.write(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_pdf_path =  "input.pdf"  # Replace with your input PDF file path
    output_pdf_path = "output.pdf"  # Replace with the desired output PDF file path

    add_colored_background(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code worked partially. The output changes the background color but overlays content. In other words, it creates a file totally yellow (background_color=(255, 165, 0)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15047017/leolaboi As I commented before: Your file already has defined some background - probably just white. This must be removed before a different background can be applied. Removal is possible using PyMuPDF, but exactly how depends on the file itself: it could be an image or vector graphics etc.